# select time range inside pandas dataframe

Tags: python, date, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have merged two dataframes (one between 1998 and 2014 and the other between 2008 and 2016). I want to plot the difference between two time series, one in the first dataframe and the other in the second dataframe.
I tried to use this [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous#10063039).
There is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
result = pd.merge(data_df, etienne_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
Z = result['1M'] - result['NNGCS01']
mask = ((Z.index.values >= np.datetime64('2008-09-22')) - (Z.index.values <= np.datetime64('2014-02-25'))).any()
Z[mask].plot()
plt.show()
```

I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "regression.py", line 45, in
>
> Z[mask].plot()
>
> AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'plot'

How can I select the time range for my plot?

Comment: Do you have a typo on the mask line?  Shouldn't the `-` be `&`?  I also don't think you want the `any()` at the end.

Comment: Well, it worked. Thanks. I tried to use [this](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_selecting_rows_on_conditions.html) before but it failed.